# How does one diplay only the referenced entities associated with specific node in a view block?

Tags: views

I have two content types that are related to one another with and entity reference field, Research project and Profile. In my block display view, I would like to display only the entities that are referenced by a specific Research project.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Drupal 7, you must go to: Structure > Views > (Choose the view you want to customize).
There you will find a section "Filter Criteria" if nothing exists press add on the right and add your criteria. You select it and continue with the customization, each element has different customization.

On the bottom you usually see the result, if nothing is shown, then this does not necessarily mean that you made a mistake (I had that problem once). Don't forget to save.